# Python: socket - running Server and Client from the same PC

Tags: python, sockets, client, server

Hy, i have just forwarded my ports and my Python Server <---> Client  chat works as expected when running the client from a different PC.

When I try to connect the client from my own PC (where lies the server file itself) then i get his error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Q1: This means that only 1 app can connect to a specific port, right?

Q2: How can I develop both my Server and my Client on the same PC, then?
(I don't have any other PC to do it on)

If needed, here is my code. (i have just started, so DON'T JUDGE)

SERVER:

```
from tkinter import *
#from mysql.connector import (connection)
import socket
from _thread import *

import sys
root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T2 = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
B = Button(root, text="Send")
T.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
T2.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
B.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)




#statick ip
host = 'x.x.x.x'
port=yyyy
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))

try:
    s.bind((host,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))
    
s.listen(5)
print("waiting for connection")
def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode("Connection with the server established\n"))

while True:
    data = conn.recv(2048)
    reply = "You: " + data.decode('utf-8')
    if not data:
        break
    conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
conn.close()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to: '+ addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
root.mainloop()
```

THE CLIENT:

```
from tkinter import *
import socket

print("everything is imported")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("socket is established")
#the public ip
host = 'y.y.y.y'
port=xxxx
s.connect((host,port))

print("s.connect done")

def sendShit(event):
    textToSend = T.get("1.0",END)
    s.send(str.encode(textToSend))
    T2.insert(END, s.recv(1024))

print("sendshit defined")

root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T2 = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
B = Button(root, text="Send")
T.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
T2.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
B.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
T.insert(END, "Type here")
T2.insert(END, s.recv(1024))
B.bind("<Button-1>",sendShit)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Just set on both files `host = '127.0.0.1'`(which is your `localhost` and set `port` to same number (for example 6000)

Comment: I've posted as answer...Please consider accepting it if you see it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both files, just set `host` to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and also set `port` to same port number in both files. say for example '6000`

Answer (score 0):

Close all the open connections for the server. Sometimes you accidentally leave a server running. If you want to get your HOST IP address of your computer, you can use `host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`. Keep port number same on both server and client.